# sklearn: MinMaxScaler rowwise on train and test set

Tags: scikit-learn, data-preprocessing

I have tried

```
scaler = MinMaxScaler()

train = scaler.fit_transform(train.T).T
test  = scaler.transform(test.T).T
```

but I get dimensions mismatch.

Answer (score 0):

If you are scaling row-wise, you are treating each feature as an observation and each observation as a feature. `scaler` is complaining of a dimension mismatch because your test set has (presumably) fewer 'features' than the train set.

It is unclear what holding out your test set is meant to achieve in this context; if you want the largest value in each row to be scaled to 1, you need to refit `scaler` on each new observation, ie `test  = scaler.fit_transform(test.T).T`

Comment: this is surely not the way to go, as then my test set has experienced different scaling transformation compared to my test set.

Comment: What do you think MinMaxScaler is doing here? You are already applying a different transformation to each sample.